# Launching a x86_64 Amazon EC2 instance with Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm using Zend, a PHP library, to work with Amazon EC2. I have created my own image (AMI), it's a x84_64 machine (i.e. not the default i386 architecture). I want to launch it programmatically from PHP using Zend. Zend provides a 'run' method to run an AMI (cf. http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.amazon.ec2.instance.html).

However when I try to run it I get the following exception:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Service_Amazon_Ec2_Exception' with message 'The requested instance type's architecture (i386) does not match the architecture in the manifest for ami-faa48e8e (x86_64)' in /usr/local/Q/libs/zend/library/Zend/Service/Amazon/Ec2/Abstract.php:273

How do I run this AMI and tell Zend that it is a x86_64? The documentation doesn't say anything on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Zend doc says you need to specify the instanceType.

For x86_64 AMIs, you  needs to specify the instance type as large,xlarge, and the rest of large types. While i386 AMI needs  m1.small or m1.medium only.

See: http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/